# Distributed Tensorflow Training on multi-node Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, cluster-computing, distributed

I currently have a local spark cluster 3.0 which consists of 3 machines. Two machines have 2 NVIDIA GPUS and One machine is the spark client master which has no NVIDIA GPU.
When I create a spark cluster, I see it recognizes the GPUs as resources on the dashboard.
I'm trying to run the example posted for the [Spark Distributor Tensorflow page](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-distributor).
When I create a spark context:

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master = "spark://192.168.1.113:7077", 
                         appName="Spark GPU"
                          )
```

I see that the GPUs are being utilized as resource executors.

However, when I run the following:

```
MirroredStrategyRunner(num_slots=8).run(train)
```

It results in the following errors:

```
raise ValueError(f'Found GPU addresses {addresses} which '
ValueError: Found GPU addresses [''] which are not all in the correct format for CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES, which requires integers with no zero padding.
```

I'm not sure why it wasn't able to detect the GPUs on the remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Spark TensorFlow Distributor MirroredStrategyRunner docstring:

> num_slots: Total number of GPUs or CPU only Spark tasks
> that participate in distributed training

Since you're doing GPU training and you want to train your model with 4 GPUs across your Spark workers, you should do:

```
MirroredStrategyRunner(num_slots=4).run(train)
```

Ideally in this use case, Spark GPU scheduling could give you an error when you produce spark tasks that don't get their requested resources, but currently this isn't the case. Make sure you set your Spark cluster confs correctly to support GPU scheduling, an example of this is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from spark_tensorflow_distributor import MirroredStrategyRunner

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("tf")
  .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
  .config("spark.executor.resource.gpu.amount", "1")
  .config("spark.executor.cores", "15")
  .config("spark.task.cpus", "15")
  .config("spark.task.resource.gpu.amount", "1")
  .config("spark.executor.resource.gpu.discoveryScript", "/usr/lib/spark/scripts/gpu/getGpusResources.sh")
  .config("spark.driver.resource.gpu.discoveryScript", "/usr/lib/spark/scripts/gpu/getGpusResources.sh")
  .config("spark.driver.resource.gpu.amount", "1")         
  .getOrCreate())

# use MirroredStrategy Runner
```

This example is from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/faster-machine-learning-dataproc-new-initialization-action